# How to access [first-name] tag from PHP hook in WPCF7? (Contact form 7 Wordpress plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress, form-submit, contact-form-7, contact-form

I've a question and i really hope someone can helps me out with this:
I created a PHP hook for Wordpress Contactform 7 (WPCF7_Submission) to send out multiple autoresponder e-mails, depending on what radiobutton users will click in the contactform 7. Radiobutton group on my Contactform is: "Packages" and they are labeled as: "Pink" "Silver" and "Gold"

Below you'll see the code:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'contact_form_autoresponders' );

function contact_form_autoresponders( $contact_form ) {
// The contact form ID.
if ( 2260 === $contact_form->id ) {
    $submission  = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();


    // radiobuttons are stored as arrays.
    if ( isset( $posted_data['packages'] ) ) {
        switch ( $posted_data['packages'][0] ) {
            case 'PINK':
                $msg = 'Hello [first-name], you choosed the PINK package';
                break;

            case 'SILVER':
                $msg = 'Hello [first-name], you choosed the SILVER package!';
                break;

                case 'GOLD':
                    $msg = 'Hello [first-name] , you choosed the GOLD package!';
                    break;


            default:
                $msg = 'No options selected';
        }
        // mail it to them using wp_mail.
        wp_mail( $posted_data['email'], 'REPLY: thanks',  $msg );
    }
}
```

My question, in the e-mail txt output`$msg` i used Hi `[first-name]` tag corresponds with the text name-tag i used in the contact 7 form plugin. When it's sending out the mail, it shows: Hi `[first-name]` instead of the first name of the user entered in the Contact form text entry.

What do i do wrong? How to show the name of the user instead of `[first-name]` tag in the HTML mail? (i prefer same to `[email]]` and `[phone]` tags from WPCF7 to show in the mail) How to do it?

Regards,
Ger

Comment: _"What do i do wrong?"_ - you are expecting the functionality that the contact form explicitly applies (replacing those placeholders in the mail template text), to magically apply to arbitrary string values that you create in a totally different context ...?

Comment: Hi Cbroe, many thanks for your reply:) Ok, well.. I'm basically not a programmer. What i need to adjust in the code to make it work and show the real name of the user instead of the `[first-name]` tag? Is it possible to help me a little bit? is greatly appreciated! :-D Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You'd have to figure out which part of the plugin takes care of replacing those placeholders with the values, and see if you can call that same functionality within your hook. Might be easier, if you just fished the parameter value out of `$posted_data` instead, and concatenated it into your message strings there directly.

Comment: (FYI, "you choosed" isn't really proper English. "You chose" or "You have chosen" would sound a bit better ...)

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I discovered the following code snippet shows the example user input from `$posted_data`: it's: `$first_name = $submission->get_posted_data( 'first-name' );` ... How to handle this snippet in the hook? Where do i need to place it?
Is it possible to help me little bit? Would be really appreciated!:) thanks!

Comment: You already got all the posted data in `$posted_data` there - so you should be able to access the value the same way you are accessing `packages`. I don't know if the value are always wrapped into an array, or if that is just because you have multiple `packages` fields - but it should be either `$posted_data['first-name']` or `$posted_data['first-name'][0]`, I suppose. So try `$msg = 'Hello ' . $posted_data['first-name'] . ', you chose the PINK package';` (or with the additional `[0]` in between.

Comment: Wow! `$msg = 'Hello ' . $posted_data['first-name'] . ', you chose the PINK package';` This snippet works like a charm! I was so long searching for this solution... many thanks again for me helping me out with that CBroe! You're my hero!:-)